# Angular JS - Getting bad argument error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm keep receiving a bag argument error when trying to use a custom directive.

My HTML:

```
<product-panels ng-controller="PanelController as panels"></product-panels>
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('productPanels', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'product-panels.html',
        controller: function(){
            this.tab = 1;

            this.selectTab = function(setTab){
            this.tab = setTab;
            };

            this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
            return this.tab === checkTab;
            };

        },
        controllerAs: 'panels'
    };
});
```

I continue to be told that PanelController is not a function and has become undefined. I'm not why unless I've missed naming it somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just remove your `ng-controller` in the HTML - you dont need that.

Comment: That removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the directive owns the controller you don't need to declare it in the html call to the directive.  You can simply use `panels.<whatever property/function you need>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have already included the path of HTML. So you dont need to add `ng-controller` in your HTML.
Html Should be simpler as:-

```
<product-panels>
     // Add HTML code here for which you want to use this directive
</product-panels>
```